# Calling custom function renders nothing?

Tags: reactjs

Im using the `material-ui-nested-menu-item` library:
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-nested-menu-item-example-b25j6

However I need to make a reusable component which you pass components to to be rendered. Ive succeeded in making a component that works with an array up to 2 levels:
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-nested-menu-item-example-izhvq?file=/src/App.tsx

However I need to make it work with infinite levels, so I'm attempting to make a recursive rendering function. Ive only got as far as creating a `customRender` (it's not recursive yet) however it renders nothing.
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-nested-menu-item-example-54q1k

I dont understand why this is happening as if I log out `item.component` I can see the text. Is this likely a qwerk of the library or am I going about things the wrong way?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Menu, MenuItem, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import NestedMenuItem from "material-ui-nested-menu-item";

const items = [
  {
    component: "Parent 1"
  },
  {
    component: "Parent 2"
  },
  {
    component: "Parent with child",
    items: [
      {
        component: "Child 1"
      }
    ]
  }
];

export const NestedMenu = () => {
  const [menuPosition, setMenuPosition] = useState<any>(null);
  const handleRightClick = (event: React.MouseEvent) => {
    if (menuPosition) {
      return;
    }
    event.preventDefault();
    setMenuPosition({
      top: event.pageY,
      left: event.pageX
    });
  };

  const handleItemClick = (event: React.MouseEvent) => {
    setMenuPosition(null);
  };

  const customRender = items => {
    items.map((item, index) => {
      if (item.items) {
        return (
          <NestedMenuItem
            label={item.component}
            parentMenuOpen={!!menuPosition}
            onClick={handleItemClick}
          >
            {item.items.map((childItem, childItemIndex) => {
              return (
                <MenuItem key={childItemIndex} onClick={handleItemClick}>
                  {childItem.component}
                </MenuItem>
              );
            })}
          </NestedMenuItem>
        );
      }
      return (
        <MenuItem key={index} onClick={handleItemClick}>
          {item.component}
        </MenuItem>
      );
    });
  };

  return (
    <div onContextMenu={handleRightClick}>
      <Typography>Right click to open menu</Typography>
      <Menu
        open={!!menuPosition}
        onClose={() => setMenuPosition(null)}
        anchorReference="anchorPosition"
        anchorPosition={menuPosition}
      >
        {customRender(items)}
      </Menu>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NestedMenu;
```

Comment: I guess you have missed `return` in `customRender`. Add return before items.map - `return items.map((item, index) => {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `return` valid JSX element here - `{customRender(items)}`.

Add a `return` keyword before `items.map`

```js
 const customRender = items => {
    return items.map((item, index) => {
    ...
```